# Intent is not detecting as expected in Dialogflow

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I have two intents **brand** and **brand_model**.

**brand** intent contains training phrases like

- latest apple products
- budget apple phones

and so on where **apple** is the **brand**.

**brand_model**  intent contains training phrases like

- price of apple iphone 6
- show me the variants of apple iphone 6

which contains **brand** as **apple** and **model** as **iphone 6**.

I want **brand_model** to be triggered if user specifically enters **model** of the product (mandatory).

Issue is if user enters "**show me some apple laptops**", it is triggering the **brand_model** intent instead of **brand** intent.

How can this be solved? Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: In my case I have solved almost all the issues, check my comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49536057/why-does-the-intention-priority-not-work#comment100670746_49536057

Answer (score 2):

if a user enters `"show me some apple laptops"`, it is triggering the `brand_model` intent instead of `brand intent`.

To solve this problem you have to train you bot for that go in the training phase and when user's query is triggering wrong intent mark that query as wrong or assign the intent in training phase.

By doing that when a user asks the same question or related to that it will trigger the intent which you assigned in the training which will be the true intent and you will get the right response .

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything wrong, but your phrases and entities might be what is influencing the choice of intent. Two things to consider:

1. What entity type are you using for `brand` and `model`? If you are using `@sys.any`, then the system has a pretty broad latitude to fill that in with anything, and it searches the rest of the phrase for exact patterns that match. If, however, you have entity types with specific brands and specific models, then it can better constrain what might match.
2. You may not have enough training phrases to give a good idea of what the user might say. So it may be picking up on the "Show me" part of the pattern for the `brand_model` intent and not even considering it for the `brand` intent. Try adding the phrase to the `brand` intent as well and see if it then starts matching better.